# Unable to connect: "We cannot fold on top of this native query" error

Tags: excel, npgsql

In PostgreSQL database Get Data connection SQL statement, if I query with semicolon (e.g. SELECT * FROM cars;) Excel gives me the following error:

Unable to connect: We encountered an error while trying to connect. Details: "We cannot fold on top of this native query. Please modify the native query or remove the 'EnableFolding' option."

Removing the semicolon (after which the query becomes SELECT * FROM cars) Excel successfully loads the data.

What does this folding mean and why removing the semicolon works?

Comment: I had a similar problem in Power BI. Removing the semicolon did the trick. Thanks for posting!